# select class starting with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

html....

first case

```
<ul>
<li class="one two"></li>
<li class="nav three active"></li>
<li class="four nav4"></li>
</ul>
```

second case

```
<ul>
    <li class="one two"></li>
    <li class="nav three"></li>
    <li class="four nav4 active"></li>
    </ul>
```

Trying to select class starting with nav like this but seems wrong statement:

```
var $myclass = $('ul .active');
var $thisclass = $myclass.attr('[class^="nav"]'); // this line
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `$("#div").hasClass();`

Comment: none of the answer working for me.....

Comment: @C-Link What are trying, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Are you trying to get all elements with class "active" and also with class name starting with "nav"?

Comment: He's trying to select all class names that begin with `nav`. @C-Link See my answer below if this is your intent.

Comment: @PurnilSoni You can see in my question I have set the variable for .active and then select class starting with nav.....

Comment: @C-Link your html class does not start with `nav` it starts with `four ..` again, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('li').filter(function(){ 
    $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0] == 'nav'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`.hasClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
var $myclass = $('ul .active');
$myclass.hasClass('nav')
```

Comment: .nav is assigned to `li` as is .active.  How would find help here?

Comment: @dc5 right then this will help OP `$myclass.hasClass('nav')`  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**.has()**](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$myclass.has('li[class^="nav"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `^=` operator will only select the nav if it's the first class in the class list:

```
<li class="nav4 .."></li>
```

You can include the `*=` operator to search for it in all the list:

```
var myClass = $('[class^="nav"], [class*=" nav"]');
```

Heres an <kbd>[example](http://jsbin.com/ujivUfu/1/edit)</kbd>.

**Side note**: This is how most icon fonts use a single class `icon-`

Comment: @C-Link so use the `*=` operator.. [Check out this example](http://jsbin.com/ujivUfu/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below single line of code to achieve your required result:

```
$('li.active*[class*="nav"]')
```

This will get you all those `li` elements, which:
1. have `active` as one of its class, AND
2. have any class in them which starts with `nav` (i.e. `nav`, `nav4`, `nav<whatever>`)

for demo please visit http://jsfiddle.net/purnil/dHRkS/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below jquery expression

```
$('ul').find('li[class*="nav"]').html('abc');
```

Please manipulate expression according to your requirement.

Also check out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBZLG/1/)

Answer (score -1):

you can directly select it using

```
$(".nav")
```

Comment: This wont work as there is no element with class="nav". What @C-Link is trying to achieve is to get all elements with class name starting with "nav".