# Select each class starting with a given string in Pure javaScript

Tags: javascript, class, selector

I would like to select any element owning a class starting by a given string, here is an example where the classes start with `fi-`

```
<i class="fi-xmsl-user"></i>
<i class="fi-stsl-map"></i>
```

I would like to do this in pure JavaScript (no jQuery).

I already read the following questions:

- [select class starting with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756808/select-class-starting-with-jquery)
- [How to get all elements by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427311/how-to-get-all-elements-by-class-name)
- [Jquery select first letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039397/jquery-select-first-letter)

The last one is interesting, but I don't like the idea to loop over each element to check the classes.

Comment: You're looking for a *"wildcard selector"*. Possible duplicate of [querySelector, wildcard element match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match)

Comment: Yeah .. wildcard was the right keyword. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` and wild card selector. Here `class^` mean that this query selector will select any element who have a class starting with `fi`

```js
let k = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="fi"]');
console.log(k)
```

```html
<i class="fi-xmsl-user"></i>
<i class="fi-stsl-map"></i>
```

You can fine tune it to select only `i` tag by passing the `tag` name

```js
let k = document.querySelectorAll('i[class^="fi"]');
console.log(k.length)
```

```html
<i class="fi-xmsl-user"></i>
<i class="fi-stsl-map"></i>
<div class="fi-stsl-map"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and specify the selector how you do in jQuery like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="fi"]')
```

And if you don't want to match other classes that starts with `fi` like `fish` but just match them with dash then you know the deal exactly like jQuery: `'[class^="fi-"]'`.

Comment: I'm having same issues, It works without the hyphen '-' but I need to add the hyphen to make it specific. Once i add the hyphen, it stops working.
Please help

Comment: @Pelumi What's your class exactly and how you use hyphen in query selector?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with the `^` into the selector like

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="fi-"]')
```

Live demo

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[class^="fi-"]'))
```

```html
<div class="fi-one"></div>
<div class="fi-two"></div>
```

Comment: I'm having same issues, It works without the hyphen '-' but I need to add the hyphen to make it specific. Once i add the hyphen, it stops working.
Please help

Comment: @Pelumi The live demo is working, so I don't understand why it's not working for you. Check your implementation

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
 and [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> `[attr^=value]`
>   Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value

```js
let i = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=fi]')
console.log([...i])
```

```html
<i class="fi-xmsl-user"></i>
<i class="fi-stsl-map"></i>
```